# Foreign MRT.exe?

Tags: firewalls

I was managing my firewall using AVG and I noticed this was allowed:

[image: The fact that I've never seen that language just raised flags]

I have north american locale, and sometimes Japanese locality(?), and that is not Japanese.  It is getting through my firewall, but I have blocked it for the moment.  I thought it was fitting to put it here; should I be wary of that?

Comment: did you tried to upload the file to  [virustotal](https://www.virustotal.com/)?

Comment: +1 to @thatguyfromoverthere. Also, have you verified the digital signature?

Comment: FYI That text looks like Arabic

Answer (score 1):

Based on the location of the executable and it's name, I think it is the Microsoft [Malicious Software Removal Tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malicious_Software_Removal_Tool). You will get this executable everytime you install the MSRT from Windows Update. Personally, I think it is harmless, and I think that AVG allowed it through as it has been determined a trustable file based on other people also having the same file with the same attributes.

That said, if you do find it suspicious, go ahead and do some investigative work of your own. Run the executable in a virtual machine with Wireshark and Process Monitor and see what it does, where it connects to. You can even do what that guy from over there said and upload it to Virustotal, though I don't think there will be any positives unless said file is not MSRT. In that case, it could be part of a infection/rootkit attempting to hide itself by masquerading as a legit program.